# database missing from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database

My developer was working on an extension and now our website's database is missing from phpmyadmin. My website is showing following error

```
(SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1018 Can't read dir of './letsmake_db/' (errno: 13)
```

I am new to all this just want to know how can I fix it.
When I go to mysql the database size is 0 mb.

Comment: **Error shows whats wrong in brief !!**

Comment: @ishan, not sure but may be this can help you http://serverfault.com/questions/20650/fixing-cant-find-file-errno-13-on-mysql